# Using non-spatial csv with PyQGIS?

Tags: csv, pyqgis-3

I have some csv lookup tables which are too heterogeneous for ordinary join so I want to process them in PyQGIS. However the csv files have no geometry column whatsoever. If used as `QgsVectorLayer` the layer ends up empty:

```
uri='path/to/csv/file.csv?delimiter=;'
csvLyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "csvLayer", "delimitedtext")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(csvLyr) #throws 'source data cannot be found'
csvLyr.getFeature(0) #returns a non callable QgsFeature
```

Is there a way in PyQGIS to query and manipulate non-spatial csv data just like any other vector data (respectively just like in the GUI) or am I required to use the csv module/another Python library?

I am using Python/PyQGIS 3 in QGIS 3.6. The csv files all have header rows.

Comment: How did you set your `uri`? Make sure it begins with `file:///` so that your path looks something like: `uri = 'file:///C:/Users/You/Desktop/points.csv?delimiter=;'`

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. I always assumed this prefix for the path is a windows only thing and also it is not required when adding other data sources... Anyway feel free to paste your comment as answer so i can mark it.

Comment: Most welcome, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include `file:///` as a prefix in the path. So your path should look something like:

```
uri = 'file:///C:/Users/You/Desktop/points.csv?delimiter=;'
```