# Pyqgis import non-spatial CSV to Qgs project

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to upload a .csv file to my QGIS project via Pyqgis. According to the following thread [Using non-spatial CSV with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314615/using-non-spatial-csv-with-pyqgis) it should work that way:

```
uri = 'file///C:/Users/denni/Desktop/test.csv?delimiter=;'
table = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "table", "delimitedtext")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(table)
```

But I only get an empty layer in QGIS. I can't find the mistake in my code. What is wrong? The delimiter in the test.csv file is a ";", so that's not the problem. The path is correct. The script uploads a layer to QGIS so I guess the line 3 is correct as well...

Comment: You forgot the `:` in `'file:///...'`

Comment: ahhhh yes you are right.... Thanks for that :)

now I have values in importet attribute table, but only one field. There should be two fields. Is there a way get two fields?

Comment: ok, so the problem was the ; as delimiter. If I use , as a delimiter I get two fields.