# Use PyQGIS to save memory layer to GeoPackage that does not already exist

Tags: pyqgis, geopackage

I have an issue using PyQGIS to save a memory layer to a GeoPackage that does not already exist. This is equivalent to using the Make permanent... option in the Layers context menu, to save to a new GeoPackage.

I have a couple of similar PyQGIS methods for making memory layers permanent. **However, both of these only work when the GeoPackage already exists.** This is problematic for the first layer that needs to be saved.

This is one method I have been using:

```
pathToGpkg = 'E:/path/to/geopackage.gpkg'
layer = iface.activeLayer()
processing.run("gdal:convertformat", { 'INPUT' : layer, 'OPTIONS' : '-update -nln '+layer.name(), 'OUTPUT' : pathToGpkg })
layer.setDataSource(pathToGpkg + f'|layername={layer.name()}', layer.name(), 'ogr')
```

Alternatively this one based on: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/455474/129409

```
# reference to memory layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# save location
geopackage = 'E:/path/to/geopackage.gpkg'

# write the layer to disk
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer 
options.layerName = layer.name()
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(layer, geopackage, QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options) 

# change the data source
layer.setDataSource(geopackage + f'|layername={layer.name()}', layer.name(), 'ogr')
```

Both throw errors when the GeoPackage doesn't exist.

Is there a way of using PyQGIS for either:

- saving to a GeoPackage without the GeoPackage already existing, or
- initialising an empty GeoPackage (my reading is that a GeoPackage needs a layer, but my understanding may be wrong!)

Comment: It's great that the answers all solve the problem simply and succinctly - I've accepted the one that I used, but they could all be useful depending on the situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following lines in your PyQGIS script to make an empty GeoPackage.

```
from osgeo import ogr

gpkg_path = "c:/test/test.gpkg"
ds = ogr.GetDriverByName('GPKG').CreateDataSource(gpkg_path)
```

If you are not going to use it in your script later, you can skip the leading `ds =`.

Answer (score 6):

Just to round out the list of alternatives, the first script can be made to work for a new file by changing the option for `gdal:convertformat` (wrapper for `ogr2ogr`) from `-update` to `-overwrite` - probably analogous to `CreateOrOverwriteLayer` vs `CreateOrOverwriteFile`.

```
pathToGpkg = 'E:/path/to/geopackage.gpkg'
layer = iface.activeLayer()
processing.run("gdal:convertformat", { 'INPUT' : layer, 'OPTIONS' : '-overwrite -nln '+layer.name(), 'OUTPUT' : pathToGpkg })
layer.setDataSource(pathToGpkg + f'|layername={layer.name()}', layer.name(), 'ogr')
```

Answer (score 5):

The second script works if you change the flag to the correct one which is  [`QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteFile`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#afda86eff21ac1da7dc42cbdde424acb1ad724e253787e753035c3706a33f34cc1):

```py
# reference to memory layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# save location
geopackage = 'E:/path/to/geopackage.gpkg'

# write the layer to disk
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteFile
options.layerName = layer.name()
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(layer, geopackage, QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options) 

# change the data source
layer.setDataSource(geopackage + f'|layername={layer.name()}', layer.name(), 'ogr')
```

`QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions.actionOnExistingFile` behavior with `CreateOrOverwriteLayer` doesn't work when the file doesn't exist or it isn't a geopackage.

Which is quite misleading since the variable is called "actionOnExistingFile" but it changes the behavior also for non-existing file (which might be an actual bug, but I couldn't find any issues relating to it on [github issues](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues).